# Calculate Average Rating System in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am a little bit confused how to calculate the average rating system. The user has completely enable to give a rate and will stored in the database as shown in below image

[image: Rating Table]

so the idea is averagestar's value comes from average rating table. For an example, prov@gmail has 4 inputted rate with average value = 4 that comes from 16/4. (Total star / Total rate)

From the code shown below, i think my logic is wrong. The UPDATE averagerating SQL is not working.

```
$sql= "
INSERT INTO rating VALUES 
(DEFAULT,'$prov', '$star','$detail', '$user')
";

$sql2="
DELETE FROM orderform 
 WHERE confirmation = 4 
   AND provider_username = '$prov' 
   AND user_username = '$user' 
   AND confirmation = 4
";

$sql3= "
SELECT AVG(rating) 
  FROM rating 
 WHERE provider_username = '$prov'
";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql) && mysqli_query($conn, $sql2)) {
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql3);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
$sql= "
UPDATE theprovider 
   SET averagerating = '$result' 
 WHERE provider_username = '$prov'";
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
echo 'success';    
}
}
```

Any helps?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot `SET averagerating='$result'` - you should update with something from $row.

Try:

```
$sql= "INSERT INTO rating VALUES (DEFAULT,'$prov', '$star','$detail', '$user')";
$sql2="DELETE FROM orderform WHERE confirmation=4 AND provider_username='$prov' AND user_username='$user' AND confirmation=4";
$sql3= "SELECT AVG(rating) AS myAvg FROM rating WHERE provider_username='$prov' GROUP BY provider_username";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql) && mysqli_query($conn, $sql2)) {
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql3);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
$sql= "UPDATE theprovider SET averagerating='".$row["myAvg"]."' WHERE provider_username='$prov'";
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
echo 'success';    
}
}
```

Edit: Added GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 0):

```css
use for fill color in emty star 
<style type="text/css">

 .overall-rating{font-size: 14px;margin-top: 5px;color: #8e8d8d;}

 .ratings {
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #b1b1b1;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.full-stars{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #fde16d;
}

.empty-stars:before,
.full-stars:before {
  content: "\2605\2605\2605\2605\2605";
  font-size: 14pt;
}

.empty-stars:before {
  -webkit-text-stroke: 1px #848484;
}

.full-stars:before {
  -webkit-text-stroke: 1px orange;
}
</style>
```

```html
star average rating dynamic from database using php 


try : - this code 



Datbase  - 


<?php 

$sum=0;

$sel_sups = my_select("SELECT  SUM(Rating) AS sum,Count(UserId) AS User FROM tbl_rating WHERE  ProductId='".$ProductId."'");  //  hard coded in here value UserId And ProductId

    $result=json_decode($sel_sups);    
    
    if($result->response==1){ 
    
    foreach($result->result as $myresults){
       
     
    $value = $myresults->sum;

    $sum = $value;
   
    $avg = $sum/$myresults->User;
     
    $no_format = number_format(floor($avg*100)/100,2, '.', '');
    
    $percent = $avg*100/5;
    
     echo '<div class="ratings">
     
     <div class="empty-stars"></div>
     
     <div class="full-stars" style="width:'.$percent.'%">
     
     </div>
     
     </div>'.'<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-target="#reviewmodel" style="background: #5F283D;padding:10px;color: #fff;font-size: 12px;margin-left:5%">Write a Review</a>';

     echo '<div> 
     
     <p style="font-size: 13px;color:#333;margin-left:1%;margin-top: 1%;">Average Rating '.$no_format.'</p>
     
     </div>';

    }     
    
    } 

   ?>
```

Comment: add some explanation why you doing what your doing or why your code is correct

Comment: Can you add some explanation to your code? Why do you think that it solves the problem? Which parts where neccessary? Please do not only post code, this makes it nearly impossible for the OP to spot his error

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple and clean way to achieve that:

```
<?php if(!empty($answer->AggRating)){ // This is fetched from your db
   $rating = (int)$answer->AggRating; // Converting it to integer
   $img="";
   $i=1;
   while($i<=$rating){
     $img=$img."<i class='fa fa-star' style='color: yellow;'></i>"; // You can edit your own html star.
     $i=$i+1;
   for($i=$rating+1; $i<=5; $i++){ // This is for non-star rating 
     $img=$img."<i class='fa fa-star'></i>";
   }
   echo $img;
} ?>
```